# Is it possible to use arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer on a raster layer?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

Is it possible to set a raster symbology to unique values using `arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer`.   Using 10.3 I am receiving an `AssertionError`

```
import sys, os, arcpy
sourceLayer = r'D:\Chad\GIS\TEMP\raster_unq_val.lyr'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "MapunitRaster_fy16_10m", df)[0]

print lyr.name
print lyr.symbologyType
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, sourceLayer, True)
desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
flds = [x.name for x in desc.fields]
for f in flds:
    if f.find('rating') <> -1:
        targetField = f

values = list()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, targetField) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        aVal = round(row[0], 2)
        if not aVal in values:
            values.append(aVal)
values.sort()

lyr.symbology.valueField = targetField
lyr.symbology.addAllValues()
lyr.symbology.classValues = values
lyr.symbology.classDescriptions = values
lyr.symbology.ShowOtherValues = False

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()

del values
```

with the error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 9, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
>       return fn(*args, **kw)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1889, in
>   UpdateLayer
>       assert isinstance(source_layer, Layer) AssertionError

Comment: Have you tried changing `source_layer` to a Layer object? `sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'D:\Chad\GIS\TEMP\raster_unq_val.lyr')`

Comment: @Paul you should add that as an aswer